# what is Super Classes of below classes

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Hi every one  i am new for Ios Development Please help any one In Advance Thanks
what is super class(s) of

```
UIPickerview,
UITableview,
UIViewController,
UIView,
UIWebview,
UIButton,
UILabel,
NSData,
UIScrollview,
UIDataPicker,
```

Comment: `NSObject` if you go up the class hierarchy enough

Answer (score 0):

Look in the Class References of Apple's iOS Developer Library where it says 'Inherits from'.

Comment: Ok Thanks Can you please send me link if it is possible

Comment: See answer above. You should really become familiar with Apple's docs if you want to continue with iOS development.

Answer (score 0):

If you press Alt+click on the class name in Xcode, you can access the reference page for that class.

Or you can view those pages online, for example:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html

If you are new, get used to reading these references, they will be very useful for you.

Comment: Please explain in detail